# How to configure applet plugin for OpenJDK in Firefox on Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, java, kubuntu, openjdk

I am using Kubuntu 10.04 with Firefox 3.6 from Mozilla's website and I use OpenJDK from the Ubuntu repsitories.

I want to know how do I configure OpenJDK with the Firefox to view Java applets in the browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just install a package called *icedtea-6-plugin* (or *icedtea-7-plugin* for OpenJDK 7) and you should be all set.

You can verify it works correctly on this page: http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Fedora like me you need to install

```
sudo yum install icedtea-web
```

Restart your browser after this.